# Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of null (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to run a simple "conditional statement exercise" with a few questions, but in my Google Chrome it keeps giving me an error. Other applications aren't giving me any errors. I also have the most updated version of Google Chrome

Warning the js is going to launch when you go to the link

Check out my [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecollins/gkoLuj9j/)

```
var counter = 0;
var questions = 5;
var ready = false;

alert("I have " + questions + " questions to ask you?");

var name = prompt("What is your name?");
alert("Hello " + name + "!");

alert("Here we go!");

var answer1 = prompt(name + "What color is the sky?"); 
    if (answer1.toUpperCase() === 'BLUE') {
        counter += 1;
        alert('Congrates ' + name + ' you were right!');
    } else {
        alert('Sorry' + ' ' + name + 'but that was wrong.');
}
```

Comment: Is working ok for me in chrome38

Comment: `Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of null` - **do not press Cancel button**. Or assign the return of `prompt` to variable and check if it is a boolean or a string before applying `toUpperCase` function - only strings have it.

Comment: When I launched the "app" I didn't press cancel but I guess I have to to wrap the conditional in a conditional to get to fully work on a my version of chrome???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not seeing that error. You can try wrapping that conditional in a value check conditional:

```
var answer1 = prompt(name + "What color is the sky?"); 

if (answer1) {
    if (answer1.toUpperCase() === 'BLUE') {
        counter += 1;
        alert('Congrates ' + name + ' you were right!');
    } else {
        alert('Sorry' + ' ' + name + 'but that was wrong.');
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason that worked. In my other tests runs I've never had to do wrap a conditional inside another? But thanks a lot

Comment: If the result from the prompt comes back empty or undefined, it will break when calling the `toUpperCase` string method. This check looks to see that `answer1` actually has a value before doing anything.

Comment: I'm confused now, when I was at work trying to build this I had to use the condition you but, and not that I'm home what you built doesn't work. I went back to the original and now that works??? Maybe some network glitching with the ip address?